# PKContact returns nil in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay, passkit

In Apple Pay,  I have used the following code for Billing address.

```
    PKContact *contact = [[PKContact alloc] init];
    NSPersonNameComponents *name = [[NSPersonNameComponents alloc] init];
    name.givenName = cartAddress.firstName;
    name.familyName = cartAddress.lastName;

    contact.phoneNumber = [CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:cartAddress.phoneNo];

    contact.name = name;

    CNMutablePostalAddress *address = [[CNMutablePostalAddress alloc] init];
    address.street = cartAddress.street;
    address.city = cartAddress.city;
    address.postalCode = cartAddress.postcode;
    address.ISOCountryCode = cartAddress.countryid ;

    contact.postalAddress = address;
```

Its working on iPhone. But returns nil in iPad

```
 PKContact *contact = [[PKContact alloc] init]; // return nil
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The billing and shipping address are stored in your instance of `PKPayment`.

To get the `PKContact` instance with billing address for a payment, simply use `myPKPayment.billingContact`.